# Firestore Nested Maps - Issue with Dot Notation for Updating Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing an issue with Firestore's nested maps and dot notation. I have a nested map on Firestore, and I'm trying to update an object within another object using dot notation. However, it seems that when using dot notation, it concatenates the called key with the object name in Firestore, which is not the desired behavior.

Here's the code snippet where the issue arises:

```js
if (doc && doc.exists) {
    await doc.ref.update({subscription: {chartslab: {
        "options.expiration": new Date(new Date().getTime()+(10*24*60*60*1000)),
        "options.updatedAt": new Date().toISOString(),
    }}}).then(() => {
        return res.status(200).send("Document successfully updated!");
    });
} else {
    await doc.ref.set({subscription: {chartslab: {options: {
        expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime()+(5*24*60*60*1000)),
    }}}});
    return res.status(200).send("Done");
}
```

In this code, when I attempt to update the nested map (object) using dot notation, it concatenates the key names "options.expiration" and "options.updatedAt" with the object name in Firestore.

However, if I update the nested map without dot notation, it overwrites the entire map field, which is not the desired outcome.

**Create Screenshot**

[image: Create Firestore data]

**Update Screenshot**

[image: Update Firestore data]

How can I correctly use dot notation to update the specific nested object within Firestore without this concatenation issue? Any insights or alternative approaches to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using dot notation to update nested field, you must add the complete path in dot notation as shown below:

```
await doc.ref.update({
  'subscription.chartLabs.options.expiration': 'value',
  'subscription.chartLabs.options.updatedAt': 'value'
})
```

There's a package [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) which can be useful in this case if you have a lot of nested fields to be updated.

```
const flatten = require('flat');

const updateObj = flatten({
  subscription: {
    chartLabs: {
      options: {
        expiration: '...',
        updatedAt: '...'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

Since you are updating the whole 'options' object, you can try this:

```
await doc.ref.update({
  'subscription.chartLabs.options': {
    expiration: '...',
    updatedAt: '...'
  }
})
```